# Strange error on c++ matlab code

Tags: c++, c, matlab

This is part of my code:

```
double h;
double sigma;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
   double *nor;
   int n    =  mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
   h        =  mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
   nor      =  mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
   sigma    =  mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);

   double *x;    

   /* create the output vector */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,n,mxREAL);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix*/
    x = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);    

    /* call the computational routine */
    createTRR(x,n,nor);
}
```

If I try to compile it in matlab with mex myfilename.c I get the following errors:

1. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' (in this line: `double *x;` )
2. error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier (in this line `x = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);`)
   and
3. error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier  (in this line `createTRR(x,n,nor);`)

I dont see whats wrong, and I also dont understand why no error is thrown for *nor but only for *x. I wrote the code with Matlab2012 on ubuntu and it worked. Now I am currently using Matlab 2013b on Win7 with Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 as C++ compiler.

Comment: Where are `h`, `nor`, and `sigma` declared?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp h and sigma are declared global, see edited code. nor is defined in the first line of mexFunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is C++ and not strictly c: you declare variable `x` **after** the begining of the code of the function. As you may recall in C you must declare all local variables before the code of the function.

Cahnge your file extension to cpp and re-mex it.

Comment: C has declarations mixed with statements since C99. Probably he is just missing the correct compiler flags.

Comment: @JensGustedt That's right but `mex` uses ANSI (C89/C90) by default, which doesn't support it. I assume you already saw it, but the command line fix is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When compiled as ANSI C code, you can't declare variables after code.  You can do as Shai suggests and rename to .cpp, or you can leave the file name alone and enable the [C99 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), which allows declarations in the code:

```
mex -v -largeArrayDims CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=C99" file.c
```

This also enables the use of C++ style comments in the file (i.e. `// C++-style comment`).

See also [Why was mixing declarations and code forbidden up until C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859424/why-was-mixing-declarations-and-code-forbidden-up-until-c99).