# C grammar compound statement

Tags: c, context-free-grammar

I was looking at the C grammer on K&R and i found this:

```
compound-statement:
{ declaration-list opt statement-list opt }

declaration-list:
declaration
declaration-list declaration

statement-list:
statement
statement-list statement
```

Which means that we can't have declarations after statements. However i am doing this really often like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Lets use a new block");
  {
    int a=1;
    printf("%d",a);
    int b=3;
    printf("%d",b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with no warning and no errors. Am i not understanding the grammar correctly?

Comment: This is a duplicate, yes back in days those were the rules, now it is relaxed.

Comment: Enable more warnings and you'll get what you expect (for `gcc` -- from memory -- `-pedantic` ought to do it).

Comment: K&R is an excellent book, but it's not a recent one.

Comment: Also [C89, Mixing Variable Declarations and Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488503/c89-mixing-variable-declarations-and-code)

Answer (score 4):

To get the error you want, pass these flags to gcc:

```
-std=c90 -pedantic-errors
```

GNU extensions, as well as more recent C standards, allow declarations after other statements in a scope.

Answer (score 3):

You understand the grammar fine. However, C has advanced since the K&R days and now the grammar accepts interleaved declarations and statements.