# Compiler error variable declaration

Tags: c, variables

I am getting a strange error that's saying that my variables are not declared even though I have declared them in main. Am I missing something?

> Error  4   error C2065: 'destination' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project36\project36\source.c   26  1   Project36

I am programming in C.

variable declaration:

```
char sourcePiece;
char destination;
```

function call:

```
askForMove(sourcePiece, destination);
```

function def:

```
void askForMove(char sourcePiece, char destination) {
    char sourcePiece;
    char destination;
    printf("\nEnter your desired move. First enter the starting position, followed by the ending position in letters: ");
    scanf(" %c %c", &sourcePiece, &destination);

}
```

prototype:

```
void askForMove(char, char );
```

Comment: Can you show whole code ?

Comment: aren't you duplicating char sourcepiece and destination in function.

Comment: I thought parameter names don't matter though. They are different, aren't they? Yes I can work on posting whole code.

Comment: Are you reading the code you've written? You have two `char SourcePiece` variables in scope at the same time (the one you're receiving as a parameter to `askForMove` and the one you're declaring new inside `askForMove`).

Comment: Please Post Whole .

Comment: Problem description is inaccurate. The code for `askForMove` is invalid (as is already explained in the comments above), but the quoted error message does not even remotely match the error in `askForMove`. Where is the code for line 26 that triggered the quoted error message?

Comment: @Shinji-san so *which* of the two local declarations is the compiler expected to choose? It does not even compile but I do not get "undeclared identifier" instead "redefinition of formal parameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full version of the code and the latest screenshot with the errors that you posted indicate that the compiler complains about the local variable declarations made in `main` function. The compiler complains because the variable declarations are interleaved with statements inside `main`, which was not supported by "classic" C language (C89/90). In order to compile this code you need a C99 (or later) compiler.

The code is easy to fix for a pre-C99 compiler - just move all local variable declarations to the beginning of the enclosing block (i.e. to the beginning of `main` in your case).

Comment: @Shinji-san Always post verifiable code , and lines that had error , it would be easy for the person struggling to solve your question :).

Comment: Sir , i need to talk to you ,can we chat ?

Answer (score 2):

As it has been noted by some commenters, one of the problems is that you cannot have a local variable and a formal parameter with the same name. I suggest that you remove the declarations of the local variables, because it's the parameters that you want to use in your function, not them.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Know that

> Formal parameters, are treated as local variables within a function.

So Here You are duplicating them and it is causing error.

```
 void askForMove(char sourcePiece, char destination) {
 char sourcePiece; //Redeclaring already present in formal parameter.
 char destination; //Redeclaring already present in formal parameter.
 printf("\nEnter your desired move. First enter the starting position, followed by the ending position in letters: ");
scanf(" %c %c", &sourcePiece, &destination);

}
```

Remove Them

```
 void askForMove(char sourcePiece, char destination) {
 printf("\nEnter your desired move. First enter the starting position, followed by the ending position in letters: ");
scanf(" %c %c", &sourcePiece, &destination);

}
```

Also Note your question is not a good example of how one should write , Always Post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

**Update**
What AnT is saying make sense , see this [C89, Mixing Variable Declarations and Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488503/c89-mixing-variable-declarations-and-code)

Comment: Thank you. But it's now preventing me from even assigning anything to those parameters. The statement 'x = 4' is producing errors.void askForMove( char x, char y ) { x = 4 } is producing errors.

Comment: 4 is integer , char is not , if you want to store symbol 4 , use x = '4';

Comment: @Shinji-san: You are making stuff up. There's nothing wrong with `x = 4` aside from a missing semicolon at the end (and the fact that modifying a parameter will not affect the actual argument).

Comment: @AnT It is char , and shouldn't it be  char x = '4'

Comment: @Suraj Jain: Why? `char` is an integer type in C. There's nothing wrong with `x = 4;` or with `x = '4';`. It is just a question of which variant you actually need.

Comment: @AnT What if it exceeds one byte. ?

Comment: Yes, I even added the ' ; ' and that's not helping strangely. Trust me I'm not making it up I will screenshot it.

Comment: @Shinji-san: Your "whole code" compiles and runs without any problems. (Aside from a completely inconsequential `system("pause")` call). So, what errors are you talking about?

Comment: @Suraj Jain: What exactly "exceeds one byte"? `4` cannot possibly exceed the range of `char`.

Comment: @Shinji-san It just shows warning "|warning: implicit declaration of function ‘system’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|"

Comment: @Shinji-san Also "warning: '+' flag used with ‘%c’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]|"

Comment: Yes, I am using system pause, not sure how to run console.

Comment: @Shinji-san Please Include stdlib , system is part of it you have not included it.

Comment: @AnT I got confused , i remember now , sometime it happen like i forgot everything and get confused , thanks. it is clear now.

Comment: Also another odd thing just happened. I just ran it including the errors and it swapped the top piece and the diagonal piece for no reason. Granted that's kind of what I want but...what??

https://snag.gy/CrmiTY.jpg

It's as if it is running off of an older version of the program. And thanks Suraj, I will

Comment: @Shinji-san: Firstly, the screenshot you posted shows completely different errors from what you quoted in the question. Why did you provide a fake error quote? Secondly, the errors in your screenshot indicate that you are using an old (pre-C99) C compiler. The posted version of the code is written in C99 or later. The errors occur on lines 19, 20, 22 which are not visible in the screenshot, BTW.

Comment: @Shinji-san  add #include<stdlib.h> and update me what happened ?

Comment: It isn't a fake quote, I wouldn't do that. I have no idea what's going on. When I posted this question I merely copied the error shown. I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong with the compiler. But it's definitely not fake. I can take another screenshot of the errors if you want me to.

Comment: @Shinji-san: When compiling C code you have to look at the *very first error* first. All subsequent errors might easily turn out just *induced* nonsensical consequences of the previous errors. See my answer for what actually is going on in your code. The "undeclared identifier: errors you get are just secondary consequences of the primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you intended to achieve in your program but you have a duplication in your variable names. Don't use the same name for the function argument and the local variable.